# Disable "Return to previous app" button in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

In iOS, when some action in an app causes another app to launch, a button appears in the status bar towards the left side of the screen, and when you press it, it returns you to the previous app (the app that caused the current app to launch). Here is what I mean:

[image]

Is it possible to disable it? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the standard iOS behaviour and nothing can be done to change it.

For more info, read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48124329/6995250) and subsequent comments on StackOverflow.

Comment: Isn't there any setting that you can change?

Comment: No. this is a feature built into iOS and there is no way to change it.

Comment: The feature was added in a major version of iOS (I want to say it was iOS 10...?) Also the feature has some exceptions (for example: going to Settings via Personal Hotspot's status bar does display a return button to the previous application.)